# ASP VB - Calling a Function From Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx page populated with data from an access database using this code:

```
<asp:datalist id="bookData" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <div align="left" style="padding:15;font-size:8pt;font-family:Verdana">
                        <div style="font:12pt verdana;color:darkred">
                        <i><b>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookTitle")%>
                        </b></i>
                        </div>
                          <br/>
                        <b>Genre - </b>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BookGenreTitle")%>
                        <br />
                        <b>Author - </b>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Firstname")%> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Lastname")%>
                        <br />
                        <input type="button" name="AddBookbutton" id='Container.DataItem(BookID)' value="Add" />
                        <br/>
                     </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:datalist>
```

I would like each entry of data to have a button associated with it that could call a server function to submit data to a database. I currently have the button implemented, but no idea how to go about calling a function that would be able to detect what button was clicked.

Anyone able to help? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `<input>` to a `<asp:Button>`, then you can utilise the `ItemCommand` event of the `DataList`

If you take a look here, this is a tutorial on how to use it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand.aspx